# Getting error when I submit one row from a table to another table using php

Tags: php, mysql, copy, submit, row

***I opened this issue under a new question***

I decided to focus on a solution that uses PDO verses mysqli go to...

[INSERT row from another table using php PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798214/insert-row-from-another-table-using-php-pdo)

Thanks guys for your time trying to help me solve this issue

***-----------***

I have two identical tables. I perform a search in the first table and echo results with a submit link for each row that appears in the results. See the following code...

```
echo "<div>".$results['Description']." - <a href='submit-ads-florida.php?Barcode=".$results['Barcode']."'>SUBMIT</a></div>";
```

The script for "submit-ads-florida.php" is as follows...

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';

$query = "INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode) 
          SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode FROM invtable 
          WHERE Barcode='".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Barcode'])."";

$mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

I get the following error and I'm not sure what it means.

> Connected successfully.
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object in /home/myaccount/public_html/florida-ave/submit-ads-florida.php on line 7

I'm still learning and I'm using a script from an example I found, so I may not be using the correct syntax for my solution. Any help is appreciated.

***UPDATE***

I've since made suggested changes. My connection script is...

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "name";
$password = "pass";
$db = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully. ";
?>
```

My submit-ads-florida.php script is...

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';

$query = "INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode) 
          SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode FROM invtable 
          WHERE Barcode='.$conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Barcode']).'";

$conn->query($query);
?>
```

***PROBLEM***
I no longer get the error, however, no data is being passed to the adstable from invtable. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post `connect.php`?

Comment: Missing closing quote, on the barcode. `'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Barcode']).""` Should have a single quote in the `""`. Or might have jumped the gun on that issue (missed error message at first). Where is `$mysqli` defined?

Comment: We need to see connect.php to know if $mysqli is defined or not, but the error you are getting is telling us that most likely is either not defined or is defined but not connecting.

Comment: I updated the submit script with the proper quotes as suggested by kiran and I no longer get the error but the data is not being copied to the ads table. my connect script is as follows...

Comment: The following is my connect script... <?php $servername = "localhost"; $username = "name"; $password = "password"; $db = "database"; // Create connection $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db); // Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); } echo "Connected successfully. "; ?>

Comment: Use the edit link to add/update your question. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32788381/edit

Comment: Answer updated. You took a step in the wrong direction. Look at the provided answers when updating in the future.. neither had `WHERE Barcode='.$conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Barcode']).'"`.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I cannot put all these in one comment, hence placing it here.

Your error clearly says "`$mysqli`" is not a object. Basically the main error is that `@mysqli` is **not defined** anywhere. Check if you have it in `connect.php`

else

I blindly! assume your connect.php is fine as you print that 'Connected successfully.'
Apart from that, You were missing the single quote at the end and; one coding suggestion is not to make it complex,

```
<?php
include '../connect.php';

$barCode = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Barcode']); // assign it here

$query = "INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode) 
          SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode FROM invtable 
          WHERE Barcode='".$barCode."'";

$mysqli->query($query);
?>
```

Note: Although you are printing that `connection is succesfull`, you must show us what you coded in connect.php, because I dont thin connect.php is coded correctly.

**Update after OP changes:**

It's clear now why you got a very meaningful error that `$mysqli` is not a object and you cannot invoke the method `real_escape_string()` on that object. You defined like this in `connect.php`

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
```

But in your other file, you started interpreting `$conn` as `$mysqli` which you cannot unless you copy the reference to `$mysqli`. like `$mysqli = $conn`.
But I wont encourage this, you should either use `$mysqli` throughout or use `$conn` throughout your code.

Comment: That is the same usage of `$mysqli` so should have the same error. Still not going to be an object.

Comment: Agree,  I wanted to add one more note taht that his connect.php is actually the issue

Comment: The following is my connect script...  
      <?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "name";
 $password = "password";
 $db = "database";
  
 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
 
 // Check connection
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
 echo "Connected successfully. ";
 ?>

Comment: I updated the submit script with th proper quotes and I no longer get the error but the data is not being copied to the ads table

Comment: @CliffT Update your question.

Comment: @chris85 Appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 1):

You named your connection `$conn`, not `$mysqli`. So `$mysqli` is not the object, `$conn` is.

```
include '../connect.php';
$query = "INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode) 
          SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode FROM invtable 
          WHERE Barcode='".$conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Barcode'])."'";

$conn->query($query);
```

Per the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) which I'd think you got that from...

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$city = $mysqli->real_escape_string($city);
```

See how `$mysqli` is assigned the connection, `new mysqli`.

In your script you have

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);
```

**Update:**

Your updated code has the concatenation wrong (which your first version did not).

```
include '../connect.php';

$query = "INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode) 
          SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode FROM invtable 
          WHERE Barcode='".$conn->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Barcode']). "'";

$conn->query($query);
```