# INSERT row from another table using php PDO

Tags: php, pdo, insert

I'm new to PDO and php. I want to move a row from one table to another with a link i send to the script below.

***LINK*** The "id" is used as a primary key in the invtable, (see FROM invtable in the script below)

submit-ads-florida.php?id=01820007985

***SCRIPT*** submit-ads-florida.php

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $database_name = "db";
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));

$barCode = $GET['id'];

$query = "INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode) 
          SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode FROM invtable 
          WHERE Barcode='".$barCode."'";

$pdo->query($query);
?>
```

***PROBLEM***

removed extra bracket by GET[id]). I'm getting the following error.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1110 Column 'Price' specified twice' in /home/myaccount/public_html/florida-ave/submit-ads-florida.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /home/myaccount/public_html/florida-ave/submit-ads-florida.php(16): PDO->query('INSERT INTO flo...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/myaccount/public_html/florida-ave/submit-ads-florida.php on line 16

***UPDATE***

I corrected multiple entries of Price. No data is being add to adstable and I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode) 
          SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Price, Barcode FROM invtable 
          WHERE Barcode='".$barCode."'";` Whaaat are you trying to do? `INSERT`? `SELECT`? or uhm, `INSELECT`?

Comment: What if I changed the link to `?id=1' OR Description LIKE '%'`? That's an injection vulnerability. `$barCode = $GET['id']);` is a syntax error, too: it should be `$barCode = $GET['id'];` (not bracket). make sure to turn on `display_errors` and set error level to `E_ALL|E_STRICT`

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari: `INSERT` with the resultset of a `SELECT` query, that's perfectly valid, though a tad weird

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Ahh, just read about it. I love it when I learn something new `x-)`

Comment: Updated the question where the id comes from

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Good catch on the bracket. I will update the question with the error I'm now getting.

Comment: I updated question with error I'm getting

Comment: @CliffT: The error message is quite clear, your `SELECT` statement selects the `Price` field twice: `SELECT Brand, Description, >Price<, Size, >Price<`

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thank you for pointing that out, I thought I am the only one who read the Exception message `Column 'Price' specified twice`

Comment: @RyanVincent - too much time staring at the screen and not seeing, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the issues you had/have were:

- `$barCode = $GET['id']);` should have been `$barCode = $GET['id'];`, and possibly even `$_GET['id'];`
- Your `SELECT` query selects the same field twice `(SELECT Brand, Description, >Price<, Size, >Price<)`
- You're also inserting in the same field twice: `INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, >Price<, Size, >Price<`
- You're vulnerable to injection attacks, still

So let's address the issues:

```
$barCode = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;//avoids undefined index notice
```

Next, to use the same field twice in the `SELECT` query, you can define an alias, but you just don't need the same field twice...

```
SELET SELECT Brand, Description, Price as price_1, Size, Price as price_2, Barcode FROM
```

Then, to protect against first degree injection attacks, let's use a prepared statement instead of calling `PDO::query` with a GET parameter:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO adstable (Brand, Description, Price, Size, Barcode) 
      SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Barcode FROM invtable 
      WHERE Barcode=:barcode'
);
$stmt->execute([':barcode' => $barCode]);
```

The code, then should look something like this:

```
$barCode = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : null;
// check $barCode is valid value, if not, don't bother connecting
if ($barCode) {
    $pdo = new PDO(
        sprintf(
            'mysql:host=%s;dbname=%s;charset=utf8', // add charset here!
            $host,
            $dbName
        ),
        $user, $password,
        [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ]
    );
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO adstable(Brand, Description, Price, Size, Barcode)
         SELECT Brand, Description, Price, Size, Barcode FROM invtable
         WHERE Barcode = :barcode'
    );
    $stmt->execute(
        [
            ':barcode' => $barCode
        ]
    );
}
```

That should do the trick. But seriously: error messages **tell you what's wrong** ***Read them***

Comment: @RyanVincent: Just noticed that OP is inserting in the same field. That can't be right at all. Besides: `Price1` and `Price2` are exactly the same field, because the `SELECT` query contains the same mistake, too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, time and putting up with my obvious overlooks. I will digest your latest comment and get back with you.

Comment: I changed $database_name to $dbName as you had in your code and replaced code after $dbName with your code and it works perfect!!! I still have much to learn with php but I will return to your example as a reference moving forward. Thanks again for your time and help.

Answer (score -1):

Please check and correct this line: `$barCode = $GET['id'];`

Let me know if this is not your solution.